# Find words to endpoint with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Someone know how to I can do? I need to find the following words to a word until the end point.

**Text example:**

**Product:
My wonderful product.**

**I need: My wonderful product**

I have managed to find the next word but not the others until the final point with this code:

```
const product= 'PRODUCT:';

let result = text.match(new RegExp(product+ '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'));

if (result != null) {
    result = result[1];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us an example. With an input and expected output

Comment: The example is Ready friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Input = Product: My wonderful product.
// Output = My wonderful product
const text = 'Product: My wonderful product.';
const product = 'PRODUCT: ';

const matches = text.match(new RegExp(`(?:${product})(.*)`, 'i'));

let result;
if (matches && matches.length === 2) {
  result = matches[1];
} else {
  result = '';
}

console.log(result)
```

See
https://regex101.com/r/ZA4qHz/1/ to debug.

Relevant docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Undoubtedly works only friend that I have an array response and when passing something like: result = result [1] does not show me anything and if I only show the array it throws something like: ["Product: \ nMy wonderful product." ] Do you know how I could get only: My wonderful product ??

Comment: Just check if match exists (would otherwise be null) and has a length of 2 then only take the second item in the match array. Otherwise the result is blank. This assumes the description for what this data looks like is completely accurate.

Comment: thank you friend at the end I served what you indicate: text.match (new RegExp (category + '\\ s (\\ w +). *', 'ig')); and I just added a replace to eliminate the word Product: